# How to implement IComparable to all properties?

Tags: c#

I have a class that contains the details of a `Match`, the structure is this:

```
public class Match
{
    public string TeamHome { get; set; }
    public string TeamAway { get; set; }
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public League League { get; set; }       
}

public class League
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country{ get; set; }
}
```

I bound a list of `Match` to a `DataGrid`, but I have a problem, when I apply the sorting on that `DataGrid` I get:

> at least one object must implement IComparable

this happen only when I have already added items to the `Matches` collection, that is the collection bounded by the `DataGrid` and is defined in this way:

```
List<Match> Matches = new List<Match>();
```

I tried to fix this error implementing the `IComparable` interface:

```
public class Match : IComparable<Match>
{
    public string TeamHome { get; set; }
    public string TeamAway { get; set; }
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public League League { get; set; }       

    public int CompareTo(Match other)
    {
        return this.CompareTo(other);
    }
}
```

the error still happen. 
So I need to ask these questions:

- Should I implement `IComparable` to all properties?
- How can I investigate more?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Oi. You implemented infinite recursion in your CompareTo method. Well done ;-)

Comment: `return this.CompareTo(other);`? That would cause a StackOverflow

Comment: If you still do not understand the problem start by [reading the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx) on the interface you are implementing. Then fix your implementation and run your code. If you are still stuck update your question with your new finding.s

Comment: Note that `IComparable` and `IComparable<T>` are two different interfaces. The DataGrid you are using seems to insist on `IComparable`. Implementing the interface `IComparable` for your Match class should make the DataGrid happy, i guess (you could also have Match implementing both `IComparable` and `IComparable<T>` interfaces, perhaps with an [explicit interface implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation) for IComparable.CompareTo just invoking the IComparable<T>.CompareTo method...)

Comment: @elgonzo could you please show a little example?

Comment: What example? The only difference between `IComparable` and `IComparable<T>` is that the method argument for `IComparable.CompareTo(...)` is of type `object`. This means, you would have to cast the argument _other_ to Match first. Something like this: `var otherMatch = other as Match; if (otherMatch == null) return -1; else {...here your comparison logic/rules between this and otherMatch...}`

Comment: @elgonzo I used the code provided in the answer but still get the same problem

Comment: The code in the answer has problems (it does not fulfil the requirments for a IComparer.CompareTo method). That said, I don't know your problem. I don't know _how_ you want to compare two matches. That very much depends on how you define the comparison rules for matches. According to your definition of how two matches should be compared you would then write the implementation of the CompareTo method. Before you can even attempt writing the method, you need to know exactly how to compare two matches, no?

Comment: Write your comparison rules down on paper first. Exercise these comparison rules with a few wildly different matches to see whether you have holes in your comparison rules. Only after you have pinned down your comparison rules you should start writing code. Whether your code will work well depends on how diligently and accurately you defined your comparison rules...

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the problem. I have to add the IComparable interface also in league object

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to add your own implementation to CompareTo(Match match) method
Something like:

```
public int CompareTo(object obj)
{
        Match match = obj as Match;
        if(match != null)
        {
            return (TeamHome == match.TeamHome
            && TeamAway == match.TeamAway
            && Result == match.Result
            && League.GetHashCode() == match.League.GetHashCode())
            ? 0 : -1;
        }
        return -1;   
}
```

And in your class declaration:
    public class Match : IComparable
without the `<Match>`

But in this case i think it would make more sense to overload the Equals operator like this:

```
public override bool Equals(object other)
{
     Match match = other as Match;
     if(match != null)
     {
         return TeamHome == match.TeamHome
            && TeamAway == match.TeamAway
            && Result == match.Result
            && League.GetHashCode() == match.League.GetHashCode();
     }
     return false;
}
```

Comment: The `object.Equals` method signature takes an `object` as the parameter. It is not generic. Also your `CompareTo` implementation would throw an NRE if `other` was null or contained a null `League` property. Finally CompareTo is generally used for sorting, doing a comparison on `GetHashCode` would probably not give you the functionality the OP is looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, using your `CompareTo` I get: `Match does not implement the interface member 'IComparable.CompareTo`

Comment: This CompareTo method violates the rules for comparison. It is not antisymmetric.

Comment: @DjangoUnchained I missed a semicolon but other than that I tested it and it works if you still have a problem you have some other problems in code

Comment: @seesharpguru, i have removed my comment and put it (in expanded form) underneath the question. However, since you edited your question with regard to using the non-generic `IComparer` interface, note that the method declared by `IComparer` is **NOT** `int CompareTo(Match other)`. Please check the documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer(v=vs.110).aspx) before editing your answer, otherwise you are in danger of making your answer worse... ;-)

Comment: Also, read again @RaymondChen comment. `CompareTo` is expected to be antisymmetric: if `obj1.CompareTo(obj2) == -1`,  it should be `obj2.CompareTo(obj1) == 1` (or whatever positive value).

Comment: Apologies. Please ignore my last (and already deleted) comment. I desperately need a new set of eyes... x.x

Comment: Additionally to what Raymond Chen said, you cannot reliably use GetHashCode() in that manner. Read its documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.100)). The important part: "_However, if two objects do not compare as equal, the GetHashCode methods for the two object do not have to return different values._" In other words, two objects having the same hash code **is no guarantee** that the two objects are equal.